# Jenkins SBT plugin fails with classpath error

Tags: scala, jar, jenkins, sbt, classpath

I'm trying to get the Jenkins SBT plugin working, which involves referencing the launcher jar, rather than the full SBT install.

This results in "class not found errors", which I believe is because the manifest does not contain the appropriate classpath to allow the launcher to be run like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /path-to/sbt/sbt-launch.jar package
```

However, this is exactly how the manual installation instructions at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html say it should run.

Have I missed something, or should I be filing a bug report (either with the jenkins SBT plugin team or with SBT)?

EDIT:  On closer inspection, it's actually failing due to "java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream".  I'll investigate this further and update my own question, as I have seen a few other people run into this same problem with SBT.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /path-to/sbt/sbt-launch.jar
```

If you create own file use (bash script):

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /path-to/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Note:
`-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` is only valid for CMS Garbage collector. If you use java 7+ you can remove it. For java 8 remove also `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M`